# How to handle a button click when it's pushed/clicked?

Tags: android, onclick

The most common way to handle a button click is:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
     //exeute some code here
  }
});
```

So I click the button, hold for a while and it executes the code when my finger actually leaves the button. When I hold it, I can't click it anymore (I mean while clicking - nothing happens).

1) Is it possible to execute the code when I my finger touches the button (not when it leaves)?

2) Is it possible to execute the code when I hold the button and then my second finger touches it (I want to use multitouch feature)?

Comment: use ontouchlistener. so when you touch down you do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Raghunandan commented, use `setOnTouchListener` as follow..

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                        Log.e(TAG,"Down");
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                        Log.e(TAG,"Move");
                        return true;

                    }
                    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                        Log.e(TAG,"Up");
                        return true;
                    }


                    return false;
            }
        });
```